# how to hide parts of an element on top of another element

Tags: css

Lets say i have a parent block level element like so:

```
#parent {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

and a child element like so:

```
#child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

and the elements are embedded like so:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to create an effect where only top left part of the child div shows up in the bottom right corner. 3 corners of the child div are completely gone. How can i achieve this using just css?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using overflow:hidden on the #parent div in combination with position values?

Something like this?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
#parent {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px; 
 background-color:#FFCCFF;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}
#child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 left:50px;
 background-color:#99CC99;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <p>text</p>
    <div id="child">
            <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```